# Login failed invalid key error when using Facebook SDK on device

Tags: android, facebook

I have gone through these links

[Login failed invalid key error with Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848067/login-failed-invalid-key-error-with-facebook-sdk)

and

http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/

but i could not understand what hash key exactly is???
where is that used in my application??
and in the tutorials he says we need to add this key hash to the Facebook application...in my case i have a Facebook web application, is that enough or should i definitely create an application for mobile on Facebook???

Comment: Related: [Android invalid key and Facebook Connect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7979389)

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start is the official [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/).

This part is explain there in [Step 5: Add your app's signature to the Facebook App Settings](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig):

> Facebook requires an additional layer of security for mobile apps in
>   the form of an application signature. You need to put your Android
>   application signature into your Facebook app settings.

Just follow their instructions, it's all pretty easy and straight forward.

Comment: my doubt is...i am not using that key hash anywhere in my application code...so where is the link??...is it that as i am using my keytool to generate that hash key it automatically links my app to that key hash??

Comment: Oh, I see, you don't get the whole signing purpose... Check out the official android documentation on that: [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)