# phonegap Facebook login button hash key issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using facebook connect plugin for using facebook api to login into my app so I used a sample project and created a simple facebook app to get the app ID and the API was Ok till I came with a message in facebook dialog saying the key "AWiYld2HXlJFTSeTlXo9NY-CTAU" doesnt match any hashed keys into your app.
So I went to facebook app and added that for android hash key that still didnt worked so what can I do to make this working, so could you help me I'm really locked up.
Thank you for helping me in advance.

Comment: did you wait a few minutes after updating your Hash key? If so, make sure you followed the steps as suggested in this answer >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979389/android-invalid-key-and-facebook-connect

Comment: Hello thahk you for replying but I waited hours for this but nothing has changed. and I took a look at the other question I followed what they did still having the same issue...

Comment: You could try to create another Facebook app just to see whether your bug is App related or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by uninstalling my test app, and then reinstalling it.

I'm pretty sure "AWiYld2HXlJFTSeTlXo9NY-CTAU" means that you don't have a key assigned.. because that was mine too, when I originally built the app without an android key.. I kept trying to add a key, and rebuild it.. with hydration on.. and kept getting this error saying my key "AWiYld2HXlJFTSeTlXo9NY-CTAU" wasn't found in my FB app settings.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution: - create your own keystore

you need the keytool of java  (jre)

open the terminal and type:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore example.keystore -alias example -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

follow the steps (passwords, name, location)

then type:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias example -keystore C:\example.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

then in phonegap build add your new autosigned key

https://build.phonegap.com/people/edit#new-android-key

thats all

reference:

http://circlecube.com/2013/02/keystore-for-android-app-development/